# Hp battery backup issue on AMD 4600H laptop

Tags: 20.04, hp, battery, amd-processor

I purchased new HP pavilion gaming laptop with AMD 4600H processor. I have windows and ubuntu 20.04 dual booted on this.
Windows gives almost **7- 8** hours of battery backup, but ubuntu 20.04 gives maximum of **2** hours of backup.
I even tried by upgrading kernel upto version 5.8.10 but it didn't worked.
the laptop is pretty new with high specification.
usually ubuntu system gives more battery backup than windows system (from past experienced).

Help me with this issue. either I have to move on windows shity operating system just because of backup issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome on board. I am having the same issue and looking for a solution for months. TLP, powertop. none of them solved.